# glib and linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, glib

I need to make some RPC calls from a module that resides in the kernel. I was wondering if glib could be used for this prurpose. Has anyone tried using the glib library inside the kernel? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not possible to use userspace libraries in the kernel. Have a look at net/sunrpc/ directory for the kernel impletantion of RPC. It's used by the NFS kernel code.